# Исходный код в документации

Tags: java, python, любой-язык, документация, javadoc

Можно ли в Javadoc указывать ссылку на исходный код классов и методов, чтобы не нужно было каждый раз искать по каталогам нужный файл? Если да, то как это сделать?

Вот пример для Python: [документация SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/index.html) содержит ссылки на исходники классов и методов.

Есть ли вообще какие-либо традиции для разных языков, каким способом публикуется исходный код? Когда уместно прямо в документации выкладывать исходники, а когда достаточно ссылки на Github?

Comment: может `@see`? нет?

Comment: Ну, это ведь просто "Ссылка на другое место в документации". А я говорю про посмотреть, как там оно внутри.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У javadoc есть опция [-linksource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#linksource), которая включает исходный код в сгенерированную документацию.

Например, в документации [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) есть ссылки на исходники в названиях [классов](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#line.64) и [методов](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#line.1053).

Если код хранится в другом месте, можно использовать простую HTML ссылку `<a href='https://github.com/...'>`.